# starting stream before producer in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is it possible to start a kafka stream before producer writes data to a topic? In other words, can a stream get started and wait for producer to start and write to a topic, and when it(producer) does, the streams automatically starts consuming it - is that feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you can start a Kafka Streams application before producing.

As soon as you'll start producing to the topics Streams uses, it will start processing the records.